# CiviEvent: prices not showing on registration page for first person

Tags: civievent, price-sets

We are using CiviCRM 5.53.0 in Wordpress and have created an event in CiviEvent. No payment processor is selected and the pay later option is activated. We have tried both with a price set and also just with simple pricing enabled instead for this event.

When we visit the event registration page no price information is shown, when we go to the event registration page for a second person there price info is shown.

Anyone has a clue on how to solve this?

Here are two screenshots, from the event registration page. For one person or the first person and for the case where two persons are registered for the second person.

Person 1 registration
[image: Person 1 registration]

Person 2 registration
[image: Person 2 registration]